# Add widget to file field

Tags: 7, entities, files

I am looking to write a field widget to extend the file field in Drupal 7. The reason is that I want to do some file parsing after it has been uploaded. Are there examples I would be able to look at? How should I got about writing this new module? Or is there a better way I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the [hook_field_widget_info()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_info/7)

```
function hook_field_widget_info() {
  return array(
    'text_textfield' => array(
      'label' => t('Text field'),
      'field types' => array('text'),
      'settings' => array('size' => 60),
      'behaviors' => array(
        'multiple values' => FIELD_BEHAVIOR_DEFAULT,
        'default value' => FIELD_BEHAVIOR_DEFAULT,
      ),
    );

}
```